# MonitorID argument in Conversation window.ShowFullScreenMethod in lync 2013 sdk

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

In the belowclode ShowFullScreen methhod taking integer monitorID as argument,i dont know what that monitorID value is .

```
 ConversationWindow window = automation.EndStartConversation(ar);

            window.ShowFullScreen(int MonitorID);
```

But i tried different values as arguments, turns out acceptable values are 1,2,3,4,5. i searched entire SDK for that values , what they imply and all couldnt find.

In a nutshell what is monitorID?? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can thing of the monitorid as the index into the [AllScreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110%29.aspx) array.

It will allow you to full screen mode the conversation onto a specific monitor of our choosing.